# WordPress Media Library Hooks and Filters passing variables between 2 functions

Tags: php, wordpress, media-library

For some reason, today PHP is doing my head in with regard to setting up some filters in WordPress, **the issue is how to pass variables between the two functions which are filters?**

I am looking to leverage the WordPress hook `upload_dir` and `pre-upload-ui` to provide a means upload items directly to the selected folder, but still leverage the inbuilt uploader.

The first function below sets the upload directory for the uploader, and when used with a pre-defined value such as `_PLAY` uploads the files to the desired directory on the server - Great :)

```
if (!function_exists ('lf_media_uploader_dir')) {
  function lf_media_uploader_dir ($upload) {
    $lf_up_dir = '/_PLAY';
//  I am trying to get the value of the selected directory
//  from the function lf_upload_prefilter, as this is a means
//  of hooking into the top of the media uploader.
    $lf_up_dir = apply_filters ('lf-upload-filter');
    $upload['subdir'] = $lf_up_dir;
    $upload['path']   = $upload['basedir'] . $lf_up_dir;
    $upload['url']    = $upload['baseurl'] . $lf_up_dir;
    return $upload;
  }
}
add_filter ('upload_dir', 'lf_media_uploader_dir', 99);
```

Now to tie into the uploader page, I have grabbed the hook `pre-upload-ui`.  In the following function it correctly displays the "pre" message so I know it is invoked.  But no matter what I have tried, including global variables, I can not pass a value back from this function to `lf_media_uploader_dir`.

Here is the second function, which currently sets a static value after displaying the message on the Media Uploader pane.

```
if (!function_exists ('lf_upload_prefilter')) {
  function lf_upload_prefilter ($lf_dir_select) {
    echo '<pre>Filter Fired pre-upload-ui</pre>';
    //Set a dummy value, later provide a selector box.
    $lf_dir_select = '/_PLAY';
  }
}
add_filter('pre-upload-ui','lf_upload_prefilter',99);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would go with a [Class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for that and use its [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) to access common values among methods (functions).

As everything is encapsulated in the class, you don't need all these `if function_exists()` nor custom prefixes for function names.

Here a small proof of concept that needs to be adapted to your needs. All your filters will fire when `plugins_loaded` is available.

```
class SO_50955282 {

    public $common_var = '';

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'start' ) );
    }

    public function start() {
        add_filter( 'upload_dir', array( $this, 'media_uploader_dir' ), 99);
        add_filter( 'pre-upload-ui', array( $this, 'upload_prefilter' ), 99);
    }

    public function media_uploader_dir() {
        $this->common_var = 'something';
    }

    public function upload_prefilter() {
        echo 'Common variable is: ' . $this->common_var;
    }

}

new SO_50955282();
```